# How to convert a varchar with month names into datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, ssms, varchar

I have a flat file containing some data which I'm inserting into a table in SQL Server database.

One of the columns in the flat file (say time-stamp) is of the form : `09-OCT-17 08.22.04.000000 PM`. I want to convert it to datetime format before/during insertion into the table.

Can anyone please tell me how this can be done?? Thanks!

flatfile input values are like `09-OCT-17 08.22.04.000000 PM, 09-OCT-17 09.31.36.000000 PM.` Expected output is: `2017-10-09 08:22:04.000, 2017-10-09 09:31:36.000`

Comment: Can you add at least two lines of your flat file, and add those lines into your question...and also, please add the expected date format that you want.

Comment: that's a horrible dateformat. I looked at the various conversion masks on BOL but couldnt' find one that fit. Maybe youll have better luck. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. I'd probalby just script out a case statement mapping each abbreviation to the correct month integer and `replace()` it where necessary. Or pre-process it with a different language. For instance, C# can do custom conversion mapping using the `ToString()` function

Comment: How is 9.31.36.0000  PM supposed to be 9:31:36??? The hour would be be 21, not 9.

Answer (score 2):

As stated this is a horrific format to start with but some basic string manipulation makes short work of this. Still not sure why 9pm should have 9 as the hour. In a proper datetime it would be 21. This works to get the correct hour. If you really want to always get the hour and ignore AM/PM you could add another replace to replace PM with AM.

```
declare @Something varchar(50) = '09-OCT-17 08.22.04.000000 PM'

select convert(datetime2, stuff(replace(@Something, '.', ':'), 20, 3, ''))
```